# Revert back to earlier driver after Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, xorg

Hardware info:
[image: hardware info]

After upgrading to 22.04 my second display began acting strangely (only half the second screen showing up). The main display was fine. I tried to switch to the tested NVIDIA driver, but the process was interrupted on restart and now nothing loads correctly on either display. I tried going back to the xorg driver and it's still the same. I think I need to revert back to an earlier state, but I'm not sure how.

I turned Wayland off and am using the nouveau driver and it *sort of* works. There are random things that won't load correctly, but it is less catastrophic than before. I'm still really lost as to what is wrong and what to even look at.

Comment: Could you state your hardware by executing `inxi -G` in a terminal. Copy the output as text into your question.

Comment: I can't do it from the laptop I'm running Ubuntu from because of the graphics issue but I've put a photo of it in the original question, does that help give you the info you need?

Comment: Drivers are actually *kernel modules*, ie. related to the kernel being used. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS GA kernel stack is the same kernel stack as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was using **if** you used the HWE kernel stack, ie. you can revert (if using HWE) from the HWE kernel stack to GA which will return you to the same kernel (5.15) as used by 22.04 (GA) & 22.04 (HWE).  You weren't specific as to what you were actually using (*Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack options, selected by media used at install*), but that's one option, which actually meets your *title* question too.

Comment: Ok I have to admit here that I don't actually remember what version it was running before! I'm really new to any kind of Linux environment; I didn't think too hard about the details, just followed the setup directions I was given. What does it mean to you if, even when inxi -G was showing that the Nvidia driver was being used, nvidia -smi didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year, I encountered a similar issue with monitors. Since it was my first time using Ubuntu, I decided to address the problem by re-installing the OS. It seemed that the error was caused by a tangled web of Python packages. While I don't believe your situation is exactly the same as mine, you could explore the option of re-installing Ubuntu if you have no critical documents or software that cannot be transferred to another drive. This could be a potential solution if you don't receive any other recommendations from others.

Comment: I feared this would be the ultimate thing to do and I really want some less annoying magical solution, haha.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that a Nvidia GPU runs with the nouveau driver (default) on xwayland.

As far as I know xwayland won't work correctly with Nvidia.
To install the proprietary NVidia driver, log out of Ubuntu, select the little cog on right lower side and switch to Xorg/X11 Session.

Log in and use Ubuntu's hardware installer to setup your graphics card